# Not able to send a POST request in GCM using Django

Tags: python, django, google-cloud-messaging, python-requests

This is my view:

```
@csrf_exempt
def send_notification(request):
    message = {"name": "xxxxx","email": "xxxxxx@gmail.com"}
    registration_ids = ['xxxxxxxxxxxxxx']
    post_data = {"data":message,"registration_ids":registration_ids}
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization':'key=xxxxxx'}
    import requests
    post_response = requests.post(url='https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send', data=simplejson.dumps(post_data), headers=headers)  
    print post_response
    print simplejson.dumps([post_response.headers, post_response.text])

    to_json = {'status':str(post_response)}
    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(to_json), mimetype='application/json')
```

Server Log:

```
[error] <Response [401]>
```

Output:

```
TypeError at /send_notification/

CaseInsensitiveDict(
    {
        "alternate-protocol": "443:quic",
        "x-xss-protection": "1; mode=block",
        "x-content-type-options": "nosniff",
        "transfer-encoding": "chunked",
        "expires": "Fri, 08 Nov 2013 10:29:45 GMT",
        "server": "GSE",
        "cache-control": "private, max-age=0",
        "date": "Fri, 08 Nov 2013 10:29:45 GMT",
        "x-frame-options": "SAMEORIGIN",
        "content-type": "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
   }) is not JSON serializable
```

I'm using `requests` which gives me just the above line.

I also tried testing some other urls where it worked!

What could be going wrong?

Comment: @MartijnPieters edited as per your comments. Thanks.

Comment: Right, so the API is giving you a 401 error response. Look at the headers and body of that response for clues. What does `dumps([post_response.headers, post_response.text])` say?

Comment: Also, did you read the [401 error troubleshooting section](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/http.html#auth_error) in the documenation?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I've added `print simplejson.dumps([post_response.headers, post_response.text])
`. Then I got the following                                    `TypeError at /send_notification/

CaseInsensitiveDict({'alternate-protocol': '443:quic', 'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block', 'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'expires': 'Fri, 08 Nov 2013 10:29:45 GMT', 'server': 'GSE', 'cache-control': 'private, max-age=0', 'date': 'Fri, 08 Nov 2013 10:29:45 GMT', 'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'content-type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'}) is not JSON serializable`

Comment: @KousikChowdhury it's completely unreadable in comments, update original post with new info

Comment: Right, but that at least told us the headers don't hold error feedback. Remove the headers, just return `post_response.text`.

Comment: When I removed headers, I got an **`Unauthorized`** error. This is what I got in server logs: `"<HTML>\\n<HEAD>\\n<TITLE>Unauthorized</TITLE>\\n</HEAD>\\n<BODY BGCOLOR=\\"#FFFFFF\\" TEXT=\\"#000000\\">\\n<H1>Unauthorized</H1>\\n<H2>Error 401</H2>\\n</BODY>\\n</HTML>\\n"`

Comment: According to http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/http.html#auth_error that means your API key is invalid. Did you try the `curl` command listed in that section yet?

Comment: @MartijnPieters:Fixed the problem. It was with the **Server IP**. The IP I put at google gcm setings was wrong. It was the firewall IP. Just now got the right IP. Now it works. Many thanks for your time.

Comment: @KousikChowdhury: np; so the troubleshooting page was correct: *Request originated from a server not whitelisted in the Server Key IPs*

Comment: @KousikChowdhury: I've posted that as an answer then, for future visitors of this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are getting a 401 response from Google, authorization failed. The [documented authorization troubleshooting page](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/http.html#auth_error) states the following reasons for such a failure:

> - Authorization header missing or with invalid syntax.
> - Invalid project number sent as key.
> - Key valid but with GCM service disabled.
> - Request originated from a server not whitelisted in the Server Key IPs.

Make sure that your key is valid, enabled, and that your IP address(es) are correctly whitelisted. The IP address is the address the Google services see when your Django server contacts the API.

Comment: I got into another problem. I'm getting `null` response in device from GCM. I get notifications correctly in multiple devices. But message is coming as null.In my GCM app Traffic Reports for API Project, I'm getting `Total requests 0 | Requests/day 0 peak | 0.00 average` Does it have something to do with my message syntax? I 've already opened another question @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19901981/getting-null-as-message-in-android-gcm-broadcast-receiver-using-django-server